# jQuery and Bootstrap Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

```
$('.inputCheck').unbind().on('click', function() {
  if ($('#exampleInputPassword').prop('disabled'))
    $('#exampleInputPassword').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $('#exampleInputPassword').prop('disabled', true);
});

BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Example',
  message: '<input type="checkbox" class="inputCheck"/>Check <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">',
  buttons: [{
    label: 'Close',
    action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
    }
  }]
});
```

How can I apply jQuery to access element in BootstrapDialog? The code above should behave like this, if `$('.inputCheck')` is clicked, `$('#exampleInputPassword')` should be disabled or enabled based on its state.

Comment: Try to put the jQuery event binding after the call to `BootstrapDialog.show`

Comment: @Piou I've tried that, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the plugin in site ?

Comment: Then try: `$(document).on('click', '.inputCheck', function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Piou It worked!! thanks!!

Comment: @RajshekarReddy http://jsfiddle.net/o5k0eaws/1/

Comment: @Chih-YuYeh your issue is resolved right?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy yep! The answer is provided by Piou